# How to track changes to icon fonts?

Tags: version-control, font-face, icon-fonts

Icons fonts are a great improvement but, as they are not text files, it's not possible to track changes using SCM. Of course, you can track the whole file, but if two developers change the file, the last person who merges is going to have hard times trying to resolve the issue. She will need to recreate the font file.

How do you track font file changes in a multiple developer team?

**Update:**
We will try to shoot an email whenever someone needs to change the file. While this may work it doesn't solve the underling problem: managing binary files with text-based tools is cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to version binary elements like Icon fonts (and not just their ccs3 text files), then the scenario you describe can very much happen.

That means, if you are not using a VCS with a [lock model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software), then you need to communicate in order for one developer to *not* change the same file as the one already being modified by another developer.

The alternative is to store binaries in an [Artifact repo](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/04/what-is-a-repository/) (like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)), but then there is no notion of merge at all.